# How can I Remove black background from an image with a negative low pixel value

Tags: arcgis-10.2, background-geoprocessing

I am working on a GPP image of double precision and 64-pixel value. The low value of the image is negative and the high value is around zero. When I tried to remove the black background using ArcMap (10.2) copy image, the output was a complete whiteboard.

Could someone indicate to me a way to solve this problem?